# Javascript to Select Multiple options with restrictions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, multichoiceitems

I need a form with multiple steps where the first step restricts options in the successive steps.

So below is an example of use:

1. User selects from 4 global options

   - If user selects option 1

     - Then the user can only select 8 options (no more no less) from a multiple choice box.
   - If user select option 2

     - Then the user can only select 10 options (no more no less) from a multiple choice box.
   - Same is the case with options 3 and 4
2. After all these selections, this form has to show a final price based on the options user selected in the FIRST STEP. No matter what choices were selected in successive steps.
3. When this form shows final price, user has to click SUBMIT button and send this result with all these options through an email.

Can someone help me in figuring out the javascript required to do this? Most important thing right now for me is to figure out 'restrictions codes' in multiple items choice boxes.

This is the form I was thinking about:

```
<form action="" id="menuform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select one of this four menus</legend>
        <label >Menu Option</label>
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedmenu" value="Menu1"
onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        Menu 1 -  serves 8 courses ($20)
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedmenu" value="Menu2"
onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        Menu 2 - serves 12 courses ($25)
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedmenu" value="Menu3"
onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        Menu 3 - serves 16 courses ($35)
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedmenu" value="Menu4"
onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        Menu 4 - serves 30 courses ($75)

        <label >Filling</label>
            <select id="filling" name='filling'
onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="dish1">Dish 1 ($1)</option>
                <option value="dish2">Dish 2 ($5)</option>
                <option value="dish3">Dish 3 ($5)</option>
                (more...)
            </select>
        <br/>
        <div id="totalPrice"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then, for Javascript code I was trying with this to store and return some values but my problem is how to force to select an exact number of options in the SECOND STEP:

```
var menu_prices = new Array();
    menu_prices["Menu1"]=20;
    menu_prices["Menu2"]=25;
    menu_prices["Menu3"]=35;
    menu_prices["Menu4"]=75;

function getMenuPrice()
{
    var menuPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["menuform"];
    var selectedMenu = theForm.elements["selectedmenu"];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedMenu.length; i++)
    {
        if(selectedMenu[i].checked)
        {
            menuPrice = menu_prices[selectedMenu[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return menuPrice;
}

function getTotal()
{
    var menuPrice = getMenuPrice() + getOtherOptionsPrices();

    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML =
                                      "Total Price For Menu $"+menuPrice;
}
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far..!

Comment: Done! I wrote a snippet of the form and the Javascript. The "main problem" is to figure out how to restrict options in the second step.

Comment: @RobertoMeijide: Go through this --  https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L813qudw/

Comment: @Abhitalks just perfect for my case!!! Thank you!!! One extra question, how can I send all selected answers in an email? Or al least get all this answers selected and save them in a text file or something like that.

Comment: @Abhitalks post your comment as an answer, so Roberto can accept and close the topic :)

Comment: @Abhitalks your solution is the best one but how can I change <option> and use <input type="checkbox"> instead for the SECOND STEP? Thanks!

Comment: @RobertoMeijide: I was occupied in my work all this time, couldn't get see this thread. Give me another 8-10 hours and I will see to it. It's nearly midnight here.

Comment: @Abhitalks don't worry, I appreciate your help. Obviously answer when you can do it! :)

Comment: @RobertoMeijide: I have added everything as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your HTML markup carefully, which helps you to target elements via JavaScript easily. Especially, using data-attributes on radio buttons for quantity and price which could be then easily retrieved in respective event handlers. Something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="menuform" name="menuform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select menu option</legend>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" checked value="menu01" data-qty='3' data-price='20' />
            <span>1 -  serves 3 courses ($20)</span>
        </label>
        ...
    <fieldset>
        <legend id='fillingsPrompt'>Select fillings</legend>
        <select id="fillings" name="fillings" size="6" multiple>
            <option value="1">Dish 1 ($1)</option>
        ...
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Checkout</legend>
        <div id="totalPrice"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Messages</legend>
        <p id="result"></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Identify and select all elements that you'll need:

```
var menuform        = document.getElementById('menuform'), 
    radios          = document.getElementsByName('selectedmenu'), 
    fillings        = document.getElementById('fillings'), 
    fillingsPrompt  = document.getElementById('fillingsPrompt'), 
    totalPrice      = document.getElementById('totalPrice'), 
    result          = document.getElementById('result'), 
    fillingsAllowed = 0, currentSelection = [], currency = '$'
;
```

Add event listeners to your radio buttons, select, and the submit button:

```
menuform.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
fillings.addEventListener('change', handleFillings);
for (var i = radios.length; i--; ) {
    radios[i].addEventListener('change', handleLimit);
}
```

Code the actual event handlers:

```
// When radio buttons are selected, update parameters for limit
function handleLimit(e) { updateParameters(e.target); }

// When options are selected in the dropdown, 
// check against the limit and reset the selection if it exceeds
function handleFillings(e) {
    var count = getSelectedCount();
    if (count > fillingsAllowed) { resetSelect(); }
    else { currentSelection = getSelectedValues(); }
}

// When submit button is clicked, 
// check the count of selection against the limit, and
// show appropriate error message
function handleSubmit(e) {
    var count = getSelectedCount();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (count != fillingsAllowed) { 
        result.textContent = 'Must select exactly ' + fillingsAllowed + ' fillings!';
    } else {
        result.textContent = 'Ok. ';
    }
}
```

And then code all the helper functions used in the handlers above:

```
function updateParameters(elem) {
    // update the limit based on quantity data attribute on radio
    fillingsAllowed = elem.getAttribute('data-qty');
    // show the amount based on price data-attribute
    totalPrice.textContent = 'Amount: ' + currency + elem.getAttribute('data-price');
    // show the hint on legend of fieldset for selecting options
    fillingsPrompt.textContent = 'Select ' + fillingsAllowed + ' fillings';
}

// iterate options and get count of selected ones
function getSelectedCount() {
    var options = fillings.options, count = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

// iterate options and get selected values in an array
function getSelectedValues() {
    var options = fillings.options, values = [0];
    for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) values.push(options[i].value);
    }
    return values;
}

// remove selection from all options, and 
// re-select based on the array used in the previous function
function resetSelect() {
    var options = fillings.options;
    for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].selected = false;
        if (currentSelection.indexOf(options[i].value) != -1) {
            options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything put together, the demo looks like this:

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L813qudw/**

**Snippet:**

```js
var menuform   = document.getElementById('menuform'), 
 radios    = document.getElementsByName('selectedmenu'), 
 fillings   = document.getElementById('fillings'), 
 fillingsPrompt  = document.getElementById('fillingsPrompt'), 
 totalPrice   = document.getElementById('totalPrice'), 
 result    = document.getElementById('result'), 
 fillingsAllowed = 0, currentSelection = [], currency = '$'
;

// listen to events 
menuform.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
fillings.addEventListener('change', handleFillings);
for (var i = radios.length; i--; ) {
    radios[i].addEventListener('change', handleLimit);
}

// event handlers
function handleLimit(e) { updateParameters(e.target); }
function handleFillings(e) {
 var count = getSelectedCount();
 if (count > fillingsAllowed) { resetSelect(); }
 else { currentSelection = getSelectedValues(); }
}
function handleSubmit(e) {
 var count = getSelectedCount();
 e.preventDefault();
 if (count != fillingsAllowed) { 
  result.textContent = 'Must select exactly ' + fillingsAllowed + ' fillings!';
 } else {
  result.textContent = 'Ok. ';
 }
}

// fire initial update based on the first radio
updateParameters(radios[0]);

// helper functions
function updateParameters(elem) {
 fillingsAllowed = elem.getAttribute('data-qty');
 totalPrice.textContent = 'Amount: ' + currency + elem.getAttribute('data-price');
 fillingsPrompt.textContent = 'Select ' + fillingsAllowed + ' fillings';
}
function getSelectedCount() {
 var options = fillings.options, count = 0;
 for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i].selected) count++;
 }
 return count;
}
function getSelectedValues() {
 var options = fillings.options, values = [0];
 for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i].selected) values.push(options[i].value);
 }
 return values;
}
function resetSelect() {
 var options = fillings.options;
 for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
  options[i].selected = false;
  if (currentSelection.indexOf(options[i].value) != -1) {
   options[i].selected = true;
  }
 }
}
```

```css
fieldset { 
 margin: 1vw; font-family: monospace; 
 display: inline-block; width: 40vw; vertical-align: top;
}
legend { color: #d33; padding: 0px 4px; }
legend::before { content: '[ '; }
legend::after { content: ' ]'; }
fieldset > label { display: block; margin: 4px 0px; }
fieldset input, fieldset span { vertical-align: middle; }
fieldset > select { width: 100%; font-family: monospace; }
input[type=submit] { margin-top: 12px; }
#totalPrice, #result { 
 height: 24px; line-height: 24px; 
 background-color: #dde; padding: 4px;
 font-family: monospace;
}
#result { color: #d33; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="menuform" name="menuform">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Select menu option</legend>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" checked 
    value="menu01" data-qty='3' data-price='20' />
   <span>1 -  serves 3 courses ($20)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" 
    value="menu02" data-qty='4' data-price='25' />
   <span>2 - serves 4 courses ($25)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" 
    value="menu03" data-qty='5' data-price='35' />
   <span>3 - serves 5 courses ($35)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" 
    value="menu04" data-qty='6' data-price='75' />
   <span>4 - serves 6 courses ($75)</span>
  </label>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend id='fillingsPrompt'>Select fillings</legend>
  <select id="fillings" name="fillings" size="6" multiple>
   <option value="1">Dish 1 ($1)</option>
   <option value="2">Dish 2 ($5)</option>
   <option value="3">Dish 3 ($5)</option>
   <option value="4">Dish 4 ($1)</option>
   <option value="5">Dish 5 ($5)</option>
   <option value="6">Dish 6 ($5)</option>
  </select>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Checkout</legend>
  <div id="totalPrice"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Messages</legend>
  <p id="result"></p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<hr>
```

---

> ...how can I change `<option>` and use `<input type="checkbox">`
>   instead for the SECOND STEP?

In order to use checkboxes instead of select, no major changes are required.

Changed mark-up:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend id='fillingsPrompt'>Select fillings</legend>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='fillings' value="1" />
        <span>Dish 1 ($5)</span>
    </label>
    ...
```

JavaScript changes:

1. Adding the event-handlers for checkboxes instead of select, would require just iterating over those:

(*just like the radios already done*)

```
for (var i = fillings.length; i--; ) {
    fillings[i].addEventListener('change', handleFillings);
}
```

2. In all the helper functions, remove the variable declaration for options:

(*as it is now no longer required*)

```
var options = fillings.options
```

3. And, In all the helper functions,

   change: `options.length` and `options[i].selected`

   to, `fillings.length` and `fillings[i].checked` respectively.

That's it.

**Fiddle 2: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hp88wdfc/**

**Snippet 2:**

```js
var menuform = document.getElementById('menuform'), 
 radios = document.getElementsByName('selectedmenu'), 
 fillings = document.getElementsByName('fillings'), 
 fillingsPrompt = document.getElementById('fillingsPrompt'), 
 totalPrice = document.getElementById('totalPrice'), 
 result = document.getElementById('result'), 
 fillingsAllowed = 0, currentSelection = [], currency = '$'
;

// listen to events 
menuform.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
for (var i = fillings.length; i--; ) {
    fillings[i].addEventListener('change', handleFillings);
}
for (var i = radios.length; i--; ) {
    radios[i].addEventListener('change', handleLimit);
}

// event handlers
function handleLimit(e) { updateParameters(e.target); }
function handleFillings(e) {
 var count = getSelectedCount();
 if (count > fillingsAllowed) { resetSelect(); }
 else { currentSelection = getSelectedValues(); }
}
function handleSubmit(e) {
 var count = getSelectedCount();
 e.preventDefault();
 if (count != fillingsAllowed) { 
  result.textContent = 'Must select exactly ' + fillingsAllowed + ' fillings!';
 } else {
  result.textContent = 'Ok. ';
 }
}

// fire initial update based on the first radio
updateParameters(radios[0]);

// helper functions
function updateParameters(elem) {
 fillingsAllowed = elem.getAttribute('data-qty');
 totalPrice.textContent = 'Amount: ' + currency + elem.getAttribute('data-price');
 fillingsPrompt.textContent = 'Select ' + fillingsAllowed + ' fillings';
}
function getSelectedCount() {
 var count = 0;
 for (var i=0; i < fillings.length; i++) {
  if (fillings[i].checked) count++;
 }
 return count;
}
function getSelectedValues() {
 var values = [0];
 for (var i=0; i < fillings.length; i++) {
  if (fillings[i].checked) values.push(fillings[i].value);
 }
 return values;
}
function resetSelect() {
 for (var i=0; i < fillings.length; i++) {
  fillings[i].checked = false;
  if (currentSelection.indexOf(fillings[i].value) != -1) {
   fillings[i].checked = true;
  }
 }
}
```

```css
fieldset { 
 margin: 1vw; font-family: monospace; 
 display: inline-block; width: 40vw; vertical-align: top;
}
legend { color: #d33; padding: 0px 4px; }
legend::before { content: '[ '; }
legend::after { content: ' ]'; }
fieldset:first-of-type > label { display: block; margin: 4px 0px; }
fieldset:nth-of-type(2) > label { 
 display: inline-block; width: 45%; 
}
fieldset input, fieldset span { vertical-align: middle; }
input[type=submit] { margin-top: 12px; }
#totalPrice, #result { 
 height: 24px; line-height: 24px; 
 background-color: #dde; padding: 4px;
 font-family: monospace;
}
#result { color: #d33; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="menuform" name="menuform">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Select menu option</legend>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" checked 
    value="menu01" data-qty='3' data-price='20' />
   <span>1 -  serves 3 courses ($20)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" 
    value="menu02" data-qty='4' data-price='25' />
   <span>2 - serves 4 courses ($25)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" 
    value="menu03" data-qty='5' data-price='35' />
   <span>3 - serves 5 courses ($35)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" 
    value="menu04" data-qty='6' data-price='75' />
   <span>4 - serves 6 courses ($75)</span>
  </label>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend id='fillingsPrompt'>Select fillings</legend>
  <label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='fillings' value="1" />
   <span>Dish 1 ($5)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='fillings' value="2" />
   <span>Dish 2 ($5)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='fillings' value="3" />
   <span>Dish 3 ($5)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='fillings' value="4" />
   <span>Dish 4 ($5)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='fillings' value="5" />
   <span>Dish 5 ($5)</span>
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='fillings' value="6" />
   <span>Dish 6 ($5)</span>
  </label>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Checkout</legend>
  <div id="totalPrice"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Messages</legend>
  <p id="result"></p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<hr>
```

---

Comment: Final question here, now how can I send this form with selected check-boxes and options to an email?

Comment: @RobertoMeijide: For that you will need to code at the server-side. You may look at PHP or ASP.Net or RoR etc whichever you find learning easier.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help!! :)